# If column Value equals And other column value equals then replace Replace value in this column - VBA in Excel File

Tags: excel, vba

[excel table of data, column a highlights store company "i-co", column j highlights sale type.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoe4S.png)

Hello, I am trying to figure out how to precisely code this.
I am trying to replace the values in Column J from numbers to sales type, let's say "New Retail"
But each store uses the same numbers as different sales types in Column A. I am trying to do this essentially, "If Column J = 13 and Column A equals 5 then value in Column J should be changed to "New Retail" instead of "13."

Here is the VBA Code I have so far but keep getting errors and can't get any further, and yes I am an extreme newbie at this.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("J").Replace _
 What:="15", Replacement:="New Retail", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

'here an example of code you could start with:

```
Public Sub AdjustColum()
Dim rowmax As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'get the number of row in row J (=column 10)
'replace "Sheet1" by the name of your Sheet
rowmax = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    
For i = 1 To rowmax
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = 5 And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value = 13 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value = "New Retail"
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Well... you just turned a problem I had for two days into a solution in 10 minutes. Thank you. I assume I can copy and paste this for multiple criterias for example I have another store code as 1 and value at 12 and want it to be used retail. Would that work?

Comment: yes it should work for any combinations.. make sure you explore a bit more the code to improve it.. this is very straightforward